# List all directors who were very prolific in their first 10 years of activity

Tags: sql

List all directors who were very prolific in their first 10 years of activity, i.e., they directed at least one movie each year, in the 10 years after their first movie (i.e., the year of their first movie counts as the first of 10.)

- Movie(title, year, genre, budget, gross)
- Director(name, country, YofB)
- Actor(name, country, YofB)
- Producer(name, country, YofB)
- DirectorMovie(d_name, m_title, m_year)
- ActorMovie(a_name, m_title, m_year)
- ProducerMovie(p_name, m_title, m_year)

Attribute genre in table Movie has as
value one of {“comedy”, drama”, tragedy”, “musical”, “horror”}.).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tag it with the [tag:rdbms] you are using

Comment: Mureinik didn't ask to add the `rdms` tag, but a tag for the specific database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the rows of the table `DirectorMovie`, so there are only the rows of the first 10 years of each director, then group by the director's name and set a condition in the having clause where you count only the distinct years:

```
select dm.d_name
from DirectorMovie dm
where dm.m_year < (select min(m_year) from DirectorMovie where d_name = dm.d_name) + 10
group by dm.name
having count(distinct dm.m_year) = 10
```